# How can I make a fieldgroup visible only to admin users?

Tags: users, entities

I'm using the [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) module to group fields on my user profile page.  I have a number of fields that are only visible to admin users, so I would like to group them together to keep everything organized.  I use the [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module to limit access to the fields to admin users only; however, this module does not restrict permissions for the field groups.

As a result, authenticated non-admin users see an empty fieldgroup.  How I deny non-admin users access to a field group that should be shown only to admins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using 1.x version of field_group module (which is the recommended version).

This problem has been solved (for most cases) in [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1131968). You could try the 2.x-dev version or use a simple JQuery script to remove the empty elements.